# BaseController parameterised constructor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, constructor, controller

I have a BaseController as follows:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    string ApplicationName;

    public BaseController(string applicationName)
    {
        ApplicationName = applicationName;
    }
}
```

The question is how can I pass a string as a parameter for the BaseController when it is inherited by the CSController, e.g.

```
public class CSController : BaseController{"CustomerSite"}
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the base class constructor from the derived class constructor like this:

```
public class CSController : BaseController
{
    public CSController()
        :base("CustomerSite")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh! forgot all about the little 'base' method, thanks... will mark as answer when I can (after 5 mins more)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base class constructor from your own constructor like this:

```
public class CSController : BaseController
{
    public CSController()
        : base("CustomerSite")
    {
    }
}
```